# How I extract text between a string name and newline?

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I am trying to extract text between a string name and the newline. The data is OCR'd from a .pdf and contained in an R dataframe.

For example output on .csv file.

```
Contract 6001 Total Hours 300, 33,350.00
Contract 6002 Total Hours 500, 500,000.00
Contract 6003 Total Hours 25, 10,050.50
```

The data is on new lines when looking in a .csv file because of the \n.
However when executing a str() command in R, the data appears on a single line and have a '\n' at the end after the dollar amounts.

How would I use regex so I extract everything between Contract and the newline for all lines?

Desired output:

```
6001 Total Hours 300, 33,350.00
6002 Total Hours 500, 500,000.00
6003 Total Hours 25, 10,050.50
```

Comment: not an exact answer to your question but you might like `unglue::unglue_data(x, "Contract {id} Total Hours {x}, {y}")`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("\\w+\\s", "", str1)
#[1] "6001 Total Hours 300, 33,350.00" 
#[2] "6002 Total Hours 500, 500,000.00"
#[3] "6003 Total Hours 25, 10,050.50"
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- c("Contract 6001 Total Hours 300, 33,350.00", "Contract 6002 Total Hours 500, 500,000.00", "Contract 6003 Total Hours 25, 10,050.50")
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the exact question that OP proposed: *"How would I use regex so I extract everything between Contract and the newline for all lines?"*, I came up with this `regex`.

```r
sub("Contract (.*)", "\\1", str1)

 #  [1] "6001 Total Hours 300, 33,350.00"  "6002 Total Hours 500, 500,000.00" 
 #  [3] "6003 Total Hours 25, 10,050.50"
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dq5THy/1)

***Data:*** From @akrun's post

```
 str1 <- c("Contract 6001 Total Hours 300, 33,350.00", 
           "Contract 6002 Total Hours 500, 500,000.00", 
           "Contract 6003 Total Hours 25, 10,050.50")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `gsub`

```
r <- gsub(".*?(\\d+.*)","\\1",s)
```

such that

```
> r
[1] "6001 Total Hours 300, 33,350.00" 
[2] "6002 Total Hours 500, 500,000.00"
[3] "6003 Total Hours 25, 10,050.50"
```

**DATA**

```
s <- c("Contract 6001 Total Hours 300, 33,350.00", "Contract 6002 Total Hours 500, 500,000.00", 
"Contract 6003 Total Hours 25, 10,050.50")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `readLines` to break it into lines and then `sub` to remove `"Contract "`:

```
# input data
Line <- "Contract 6001 Total Hours 300, 33,350.00
Contract 6002 Total Hours 500, 500,000.00
Contract 6003 Total Hours 25, 10,050.50"

sub("Contract ", "", readLines(textConnection(Line)))
## [1] "6001 Total Hours 300, 33,350.00"  
## [2] "6002 Total Hours 500, 500,000.00"
## [3] "6003 Total Hours 25, 10,050.50"
```